# (ReactNative) How to export variable in componentDidmount?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I don't like global variables.
However I need import a variable from fileA to fileB.
I don't want to use redux.

I just pass a variable(color) in componentDidmount to another file.

Do you have any idea?

for example

```
// fileA
class A extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const foo = 'string';
  }
}

// fileB
import { foo } from './fileA';
alert(foo);
```

I want do like that.

Comment: It would be better to understand the problem, if you provide an example.

Comment: Is it possible that you're thinking the other way around for example, if fileB uses this variable you could put it into state management (mobx, redux, ...), when fileB is a child prop you could pass foo as a property off that Component and if it's a function use just call fileB when needed

Comment: fileA is outof Provider
and moving fileA in Provider destroy design.
'string' is immutable
I just use 'string' in only two files.

Comment: What you're trying to do can never work. `A#componentDidMount` will only run after the import from file B has been run, so it won't be available like that. I suggest you expand your question with what you are trying to achieve, in a bigger picture, and maybe someone can help with that.